# Simulate microsoft word with silverlight

Tags: silverlight, ms-word, ms-office

Does anyone know of a way to simulate microsoft word using silverlight in a web browser? I am not looking for a commercial application but rather an open source solution. I do not need the complete functionality of word. Something simple that will display the text of a document will do for the first version. Also, silverlight cannot be running in out-of-browser mode and I cannot use a WCF service.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the [Silverlight Text Editor](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/samplebrowser/#/?sref=RichNotepadSnippets) in Microsoft Sample.